# What causes asymmetry in the number of `\` required for vim exec?

Tags: vim

Consider the following file, stolen shamelessly from [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/16.html).

```
Topic One
=========

This is some text about topic one.

It has multiple paragraphs.

Topic Three
--------

Hello World
Topic Two
=========

This is some text about topic two.  It has only one paragraph.
```

Suppose I am trying to find the text above both types of headings, and I write the following expression.

```
:onoremap <buffer> ih :<c-u>execute "normal! ?^\\(==\\+\\|--\\+\\)$\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
```

This mapping does not work, seemingly because the expression `\\|` gets converted to `|`. On the other hand, the following mapping does work.

```
:onoremap <buffer> ih :<c-u>execute "normal! ?^\\(==\\+\\\\|--\\+\\)$\r:nohlsearch\rkvg_"<cr>
```

This seems highly counterintuitive, because `\(` can be represented with `\\(` in the string, and `\+` can be represented with `\\+` in the string.

**Why does `\|` require `\\\\|` to represent?**

I'm trying to get a mental model for the cause, so I can reason about future cases like this.

Comment: `:help map-bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslashes inside the double quotes just need to be escaped *once*, so that `"\\("` gives `'\"`. The `|` however needs to be escaped *twice*, once for the double quotes, and once again because otherwise it would conclude the `:map` command. For that reason, I strongly recommend to use `<Bar>` instead of `\|` inside of mappings. This is documented under [`:help map-bar`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#map-bar).